# Windows 8: Audio and video streaming out of sync

Tags: windows-8, streaming

My Windows 8 laptop streams audio and video that is out of sync. I have noticed this when streaming from 2 separate sites, so its not related to a particular site. My Windows 7 PC that streams from the same router (both through WiFi) has no such problems with the same sites.

One of the sites uses Silverlight while the other site uses Flash. Also, I've tried different browsers but the issue remains.

Can anyone advise on ways to fix this as it is quite annoying? I don't recall ever having such issues before I upgraded to Windows 8 from Vista so not sure what the problem is.

Thanks

Comment: Are the video drivers on the laptop up to date? What sort of graphics hardware does it have? Also, just to confirm, the *same* laptop with Vista was fine, but upgraded to Win8 isn't?

Comment: Yes, was fine beforehand, I verified that the drivers are up to date. I don't have the hardware to hand but I know it's NVidia. Any other ideas? Thinking of just reinstalling Windows 7 to resolve